# Docker-compose exits immediately with PostgreSQL container: Invalid primary checkpoint record

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am facing an issue with my Docker-compose setup for a PostgreSQL container. Up until today, it was running smoothly without any problems. However, starting today, the container exits immediately after launching, and I can't figure out the cause.

Here's the relevant section of my docker-compose.yml for the PostgreSQL service:

```
postgres:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  ports:
    - '5432:5432'
  volumes: 
    - ./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Upon checking the container logs after an unsuccessful attempt, I found the following:

```
2023-07-16 14:42:05 
2023-07-16 14:42:05 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2023-07-16 14:42:05 
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.446 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.446 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.446 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.448 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.453 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-07-14 20:15:24 UTC
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.453 UTC [29] LOG:  WAL file is from different database system: WAL file database system identifier is 7240036120792645671, pg_control database system identifier is 7251518576611741736
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.453 UTC [29] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.453 UTC [29] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.453 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 29) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.454 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2023-07-16 14:42:05 2023-07-16 11:42:05.454 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Looks like corruption.  Restore from a backup.  To figure out what happened, you should look in the earlier logs, from when the corruption happened, as opposed to when it was detected.

Comment: Did you use your volume "./volumes/postgres" for something else? It looks like you did. For normal shutdown and start - up procedures PostgreSQL works fine. Probably, there is an external intervention. It might be that you used docker compose up(it should not work for the second instance, but the idea is same, another database UUID is being used)?

Comment: Thanks @UmutTEKİN There is an additional service that uses the PostgreSQL image, but its volume path is different: "tool_postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data." To resolve the issue, I updated volume path from "./volumes/postgres:/var" to "postgres-data:/var.". I am not sure but maybe there is something wrong about docker it was looking the same volume even paths are different.

Comment: No, that won' t help. If you did something like this in advance that might be the reason. You need to use the data volume that you used at the first place. If that does not work, there is no other chance than restoring the backup as @jjanes mentioned as a last resort.